# Extract name=value content from within HTML comment tags

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to grab the content from some Craigslist tags in PHP/Codeigniter. The tags I need to parse look like:

```
<!-- CLTAG xstreet0=Inman -->
<!-- CLTAG xstreet1=Moscrop -->
<!-- CLTAG city=Burnaby -->
<!-- CLTAG region=BC -->
```

For each one of these tags, which are contained in a $content variable, I'd like to grab each name/value pair. Tragically, I am the SUCK with regular expressions, but so far this at least finds the opening string of one of the tags:

```
$pattern = '/<!-- CLTAG city=/';
preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

Where I'm stuck is now to pull a pair of name/value out, so that I have 'city' and 'burnaby' to work with. Ditto for each of the others. I suspect a substr or something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your life a bit easier by including the "PREG_SET_ORDER" constant and [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead of [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like so:

```
$content = "
<!-- CLTAG xstreet0=Inman -->
<!-- CLTAG xstreet1=Moscrop -->
<!-- CLTAG city=Burnaby -->
<!-- CLTAG region=BC -->
";

$pattern = '/<!--\sCLTAG\s([^=]+)=([^\s]+)\s-->/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
  echo 'key: ' . $match[1] . ' | value: ' . $match[2] . "\n";
}
```

If you encountered a scenario where no "xstreet1" value was specified (because addresses can work that way), you would need to slightly modify the regex pattern and add a check to ensure the second group exists in your loop:

```
$pattern = '/<!--\sCLTAG\s([^=]+)=([^\s]+)?\s-->/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
  echo 'key: ' . $match[1] . ' | value: ';
  echo empty($match[2]) ? 'N/A' : $match[2];
  echo "\n";
}
```

Note how there's a '?' added after the second capture group in the regular expression. This tells the regex compiler that this group may or may not occur.

Comment: Hmm, one thing I'm noticing and it's odd. It's picking up the 'city' and 'region' tags properly, but not the 'xstreet0' or 'xstreet1'.

Comment: Can you give me an example tag list where it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Sure thing. If you look here:http://vancouver.en.craigslist.ca/bnc/apa/2737049936.html, around line 96 and 97. Is it possible the regular expression isn't accounting for the digit in the string?

Comment: This particular one is failing specifically because there is no value specified for xstreet1. I'm tempted to let you research how to edit the regex to account for this on your own :)  But I'm in a good mood, so I'll update my answer. In progress ...

Comment: That's fair enough, and I am digging through it. But I do appreciate the time you took to help further. Cheers!

Comment: That got the missing value scenario, but I've discovered the key problem I was having and that is, if there's more than one word in the 'xstreet0' value, it doesn't get found.

Comment: Ended up with $pattern = '/<!--\sCLTAG\s([^=]+)=(\w+(\s\w+)*)([^\s]+)?\s-->/';

Comment: See! I knew you could do it :) My brain got trapped in the exact examples we were looking at and they were all one word. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/<!-- CLTAG ([^=]+)=([^\s]+) -->/';

preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
```

$matches[1] should be equal to your attribute, and $matches[2] should be equal to your value.

I guessed the filters based on the data you provided, they might need to be tweaked.